# Solution for Mass Deletion

Tags: npsp

currently, we have "households" listed for many of our contacts. We do not want them. Is there a way to delete all households from our account, and also to turn it off? It seems like every time we add a new contact there is a new household created. We do not want that. I need a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Households are created in NPSP by default. You can suppress this behavior by going to Setup > Installed Packages > Configure (NPSP package). On the configuration screen, you should have an option to suppress creating households. I found [this post](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gzzoAAA) that explains how to do so, but it may be outdated.

Comment: For example, we do many dealings with school districts. So say we have a teacher in a school district that we have contact with, this person would be listed with all their information, and their account would be either their high school or their school district.

The problem we are having is that many non-profits use households for fundraising, but we do not do fund raising. We handle things more like a business, so the households are useless. The problem is that there are MANY of them in our salesforce, and somehow they keep being created and we're not sure how. We need this to stop.

Comment: @Raj Let me dig into this a bit more and see if I can find a more concrete answer for you.

Comment: @Raj I may have found an answer--see my new version.